# Unable to connect to apache virtualhost

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter-3

I have  unizped codeigniter on `/var/www/control_cuotas` indx.php is placed on that folder and I settrd up a new virtualhost on apache on the `000-default.conf` file  whith this code

```
<VirtualHost *:81>

        <Directory /var/www/control_cuotas>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/control_cuotas
        ServerAlias www.control_cuotas.test


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

But I cannot acces to `localhost:81` its `Unable to connect` and the serve rwas restarted before I tried to access

Comment: Why on port 81? Set that back to 80. Give it a `ServerName control_cuotas.test` and then address it normally in the address bar as `control_cuotas.test`

Comment: You will also probably have to add `127.0.0.1 control_cuotas.test` and `::1 control_cuotas.test` to your HOSTS file if you dont have a DNS Server doing that for you

Comment: I use the port 81 because 80 it0s already in use by another virtualhost

Comment: You can have 1000 Virtual Hosts ALL using port 80. Thats how Hosting companies do it. As long as the `ServerName` is different Apache can differentiate between VH even on the same port

Comment: @RiggsFolly ,but the way I setted should work doesn 't?

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: **You dont have** a `ServerName control_cuotas.test` in your VH definition. You only have a `ServerAlias`

Comment: I'have two more virtualhosts on the same file without ServerName and working

Comment: Linux or Windows Server???

Comment: if you use VHost need ServerName and Add it to your network address

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: It's ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I added ServerName and the direccion on /etc/hosts but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName your_project
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/your_project"
  <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/your_project/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try one more time.

Make sure all your VirtualHosts define a ServerName. Failure to do so will mean trouble as you add more hosts.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/control_cuotas
    ServerName control_cuotas.test
    ServerAlias www.control_cuotas.test
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    <Directory /var/www/control_cuotas>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to enable the above config in Apache adding it to the sites-enabled list. Then restart Apache.

The file `/etc/hosts` should look like this at a minimum

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   control_cuotas.test
127.0.0.1   www.control_cuotas.test
```

Other VHosts should also be represented in this file.

You can also add entries for ipV6 if you want, but it is not a requirement in most cases. (The main case is that you have disabled communication using ipV4.)